# Detect old cache images in Magento 2

Tags: product-images, cache, magento2.2.8

Due to some mistake we ended up in cached thumbnail images for old versions of our images in Magento 2.2.8 shop.

How can we detect those images? Is there a build in function for this?

We want to avoid a full cache-delete and `bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

So our idea would be

1. traverse over all images on the file system
2. find all the cached versions
3. check if a the cached version has on older time stamp than the original image

Did anybody do this already? Is there an easier solution?